# How to make a button stop counting below 0, using Java?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I'm stuck with this code:

```
private static String labelPrefix = "Number of  boats added: ";
private int numClicks = 0;

     JLabel addb = new JLabel(labelPrefix + "0    "); 
     JButton del = new JButton("Delete Boat!"); 

        panel.add(addb);
         addb.setText(labelPrefix + --numClicks);
          del.setVisible(true);
```

When delete button is pressed it counts down from labelPrefix, but I need it to stop at 0 and not go to negative side. Any ideas how I could do it without changing a lot?

Comment: First, please format your code when posting here to reduce irritation (e.g. due to wrong intendation) and show some effort. Second, try `del.setVisible(numClicks > 0);`

Comment: Sorry but do you mean the structure? it works but when it goes at 0 the button disapears

Comment: Please don't post code that makes no sense.

Comment: Thank You Thomas It works!!!

Comment: @JustRegularGuy by "formatting" I mean your post, look at it you'll see a lot of strange intendation. Ofc the button is invisible then, if you want to do sth. else do that - the question is what you want to do in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max(0, yourPossiblyNegativeValue)`?
`if (yourPossiblyNegativeValue > 0) { /*do the work*/ }`?